Simple proof that $(3+\frac{1}{x_1}) (3+\frac{1}{x_2}) = 2^y \implies x_1 = x_2 = 1$ (where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are odd, and $y\geq2$)
I am looking for a simple proof of the following fact : for all pairs of odd positive integers $x_1$ and $x_2$, if there exists an integer $y \geq 2$ such that $\left( 3 + \frac{1}{x_{1}} \right) \left( 3 + \frac{1}{x_{2}} \right) = 2^y$, then we necessarily have $x_1 = x_2 = 1$.
I already know how to prove it, but the proof I found is a bit tedious. It can be found at the end of this post.
I am also wondering if this property can be generalized, i.e. if we have : for all integers $p \geq 1$, for all $p$-tuples of odd positive integers $(x_1, \dots, x_{p})$, if there exists an integer $y \geq p$ such that $\prod_{i = 1}^{p} \left( 3 + \frac{1}{x_{i}} \right) = 2^y$, then do we necessarily have $x_1 = x_2 = \dots = x_p = 1$ ? And if it can be generalized, how could it be proven ? I tried using induction, but it didn't lead me anywhere.
##################################################################
Here is my current proof of the initial statement. Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be odd positive integers, and let $y \geq 2$ be an integer such that $\left( 3 + \frac{1}{x_{1}} \right) \left( 3 + \frac{1}{x_{2}} \right) = 2^y$. Let's show that $x_1 = x_2 = 1$.
• Case 1 : $x_1 = 1$
In that case, we have $3 + \frac{1}{x_{1}} = 4 = 2^2$, so we get $3 + \frac{1}{x_{2}} = 2^{y-2}$, i.e. $\frac{1}{x_{2}} = 2^{y-2} - 3$. Since $y \geq 2$, $2^{y-2} - 3$ is an integer, so we also have that $\frac{1}{x_{2}}$ is an integer. Therefore, given that $x_2$ is an odd positive integer, we necessarily have $x_2 = 1$ (and $y=4$).
• Case 2 : $x_2 = 1$
Exactly like in the first case, we show that we necessarily have $x_1 = 1$.
• Case 3 : Let's assume that $x_1 \neq 1$ and $x_2 \neq 1$. We want to show that this assumption leads to a contradiction.
Because $x_1$ and $x_2$ are odd positive integers, in this case we necessarily have that $x_1 \geq 3$ and $x_2 \geq 3$.
We have : $$\begin{aligned} 2^{y} - 10 &= \left( 3 + \frac{1}{x_{1}} \right) \left( 3 + \frac{1}{x_{2}} \right) - 10\\ &= \frac{(3 x_1 + 1) (3 x_2 + 1)}{x_1 x_2} - 10 \\ &= \frac{9 x_1 x_2 + 3 x_1 + 3 x_2 + 1}{x_1 x_2} - 10 \\ &= \frac{10 x_1 x_2 - x_1 x_2 + 3 x_1 + 3 x_2 + 1}{x_1 x_2} - 10 \\ &= \frac{(3 x_1 + 1) + (3 - x_1) x_2 }{x_1 x_2} + 10 - 10 \\ &= \frac{(3 x_1 + 1) + (3 - x_1) x_2 }{x_1 x_2} \\ &= \frac{2 \left[ \left( \frac{3 x_1 + 1}{2} \right) + \left( \frac{3 - x_1}{2} \right) x_2 \right] }{x_1 x_2} \quad \quad \quad \textbf(*) \end{aligned}$$
Note that, because $x_1$ is an odd integer, $3 x_1 + 1$ and $3 - x_1$ are even integers, implying that $\frac{3 x_1 + 1}{2}$ and $\frac{3 - x_1}{2}$ are integers, implying that $\left( \frac{3 x_1 + 1}{2} \right) + \left( \frac{3 - x_1}{2} \right) x_2$ is also an integer. Additionally, since $2^{y} - 10$ is an integer, so is $\frac{2 \left[ \left( \frac{3 x_1 + 1}{2} \right) + \left( \frac{3 - x_1}{2} \right) x_2 \right] }{x_1 x_2}$ (by $(*)$), and therefore $x_1 x_2$ divides $2 \left[ \left( \frac{3 x_1 + 1}{2} \right) + \left( \frac{3 - x_1}{2} \right) x_2 \right]$. But because $x_1 x_2$ is odd (and $x_1 x_2 \neq 1$), $x_1 x_2$ necessarily divides $\left( \frac{3 x_1 + 1}{2} \right) + \left( \frac{3 - x_1}{2} \right) x_2$.
Now let's show that $x_1 x_2 > \left| \left( \frac{3 x_1 + 1}{2} \right) + \left( \frac{3 - x_1}{2} \right) x_2 \right|$.
We have : $$\begin{aligned} x_1 \geq 3 \text{ and } x_2 \geq 3 &\implies (x_1 - 1) (x_2 - 1) \geq 4 \\ &\implies (x_1 - 1) (x_2 - 1) \geq \frac{5}{3} \\ &\implies x_1 x_2 - x_1 - x_2 + 1 \geq \frac{5}{3} \\ &\implies x_1 x_2 \geq x_1 + x_2 + \frac{2}{3} \\ &\implies 3 x_1 x_2 \geq 3 x_1 + 3 x_2 + 2 \\ &\implies 3 x_1 x_2 - 1 \geq 3 x_1 + 3 x_2 + 1 \\ &\implies 3 x_1 x_2 > 3 x_1 + 3 x_2 + 1 \\ &\implies 3 x_1 x_2 > 3 x_1 + 3 x_2 + 1 > - x_1 x_2 \\ &\implies 2 x_1 x_2 > 3 x_1 + 3 x_2 + 1 - x_1 x_2 > - 2 x_1 x_2 \\ &\implies x_1 x_2 > \left( \frac{3 x_1 + 1}{2} \right) + \left( \frac{3 - x_1}{2} \right) x_2 > - x_1 x_2 \\ &\implies x_1 x_2 > \left| \left( \frac{3 x_1 + 1}{2} \right) + \left( \frac{3 - x_1}{2} \right) x_2 \right| \end{aligned}$$
Because $\vert x_1 x_2 \vert = x_1 x_2$, we now have :
\begin{cases} x_1 x_2 \text{ divides } \left( \frac{3 x_1 + 1}{2} \right) + \left( \frac{3 - x_1}{2} \right) x_2 \\ \vert x_1 x_2 \vert > \left| \left( \frac{3 x_1 + 1}{2} \right) + \left( \frac{3 - x_1}{2} \right) x_2 \right| \end{cases}
Therefore we necessarily have $\left( \frac{3 x_1 + 1}{2} \right) + \left( \frac{3 - x_1}{2} \right) x_2 = 0$. $\quad \quad (**)$
Case 3.1 : $x_1 = 3$
Then, by $(**)$, we have $5=0$ : contradiction.
Case 3.2 : $x_1 \neq 3$ (therefore here we have $x_1 \geq 5$)
Then we get : $$\begin{aligned} \left( \frac{3 x_1 + 1}{2} \right) + \left( \frac{3 - x_1}{2} \right) x_2 = 0 &\implies x_2 = \frac{3 x_1 + 1}{x_1 - 3} \\ &\implies x_2 = \frac{3 x_1 - 9 + 10}{x_1 - 3} \\ &\implies x_2 = \frac{3 ( x_1 - 3) + 10}{x_1 - 3} \\ &\implies x_2 = 3 + \frac{10}{x_1 - 3} \quad \quad (***) \\ &\implies x_2 - 3 = \frac{10}{x_1 - 3} \\ &\implies \frac{10}{x_1 - 3} \text{ is an integer} \\ &\implies (x_1 - 3) \text{ divides } 10 \quad (****) \end{aligned}$$
Since $x_1$ is odd and $x_1 \geq 5$, $x_1 - 3$ is even and $x_1 - 3 \geq 2 > 0$. Therefore, by $(****)$, $x_1 - 3$ is an even positive factor of $10$, so $x_1 - 3 = 2 \text{ or } 10$, so $x_1 = 5 \text{ or } 13$. Then $(***)$ gives us : $x_2 = 8 \text{ or } 4$. This is a contradiction, as $x_2$ is odd.
$\implies$ So the third case always yields a contradiction, which concludes this proof !

Try not to mix formal and informal notation. $(2\mathbb  N+1)^2$ is informal.) Formal notation, in small quantities are fine, but in a long sentence like this, just use English. Your title is much less work to understand, no reason for the notation.

@ThomasAndrews while I agree that words are easier to understand, there's nothing informal about $(2\mathbb N+1)^2$

If you already know a proof, outline it for us so we can avoid duplicating what you know. Help people help you.

@ThomasAndrews Thanks for the feedback. I edited my post to make it more readable. My proof was also added, as you suggested.

The terms odd positive numbers mentioned, allows us to say that $$3<\bigg(3+\frac 1x_1\bigg),\bigg(3+\frac 1x_2\bigg)≤4\\
\implies 9<\bigg(3+\frac 1x_1\bigg)\bigg(3+\frac 1x_2\bigg)≤16$$
Hence $y=4$ because $y\in\mathbb{Z^+}$
$\text{Proof:-}$
$$\bigg(3+\frac 1x_1\bigg)\bigg(3+\frac 1x_2\bigg)=16\\\implies x_2=\frac{3x_1+1}{7x_1-3}$$
For $x_2$ to be an integer, $$7x_1-3≤3x_1+1\implies x_1≤1$$
Hence $x_1=1$ as $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{Z^+}$
From the equation we get $x_2=1$.
Thus $$x_1=x_2=1,y=4$$

Thanks @CalvinLin , I understand, But can I get any help in proving it. :") This looks so trivial

@Gwen Given that this is essentially equivalent to the Collatz conjecture, I'm going to say no to helping you since I'd prefer to keep all the credit to myself if I could solve it. $\quad$ :p

@CalvinLin WHAT? This can be linked to the Collatz conjecture? This is like Darth Vader saying he is Luke's father
